# Programmatically test if device fingerprint works correctly

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

Is there a way to test programatically that my phone's fingerprint sensor, works correctly?
I would like to be able to perform the test automatically, without enrolling my fingerprint and then trying to login with it to see if the sensor is working.

Comment: what is your minimum sdk ?

Comment: Minimim sdk is 22

Comment: too far back, maximum i can give you is 23 ;)

Comment: There's no `isFingerprintSensorWorkingCorrectly`. You'll just have to try to do an authentication.

Comment: how about to add a fingerprint programatically? and then try to login somehow...I want to do this test as automatically as possible.

Answer (score 0):

SDK 23 +

```
fun isHardwareSupported(context: Context): Boolean {
   val fingerprintManager = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context)
   return fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected
}
```

SDK 28+

```
fun isHardwareSupported(context: Context): Boolean {
  val pm = context.packageManager
  return pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_FINGERPRINT)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to test the sensor,if it functions correctly. This is my question.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use `BiometricManager` androidx Library

The method can be used to determine if biometric hardware is present and if the user is enrolled or not.

```
fun isHardwareSupported(context: Context): Boolean {
    return BiometricManager.from(context).canAuthenticate() != BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE)
}
```

> Returns BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED if the user does not have any enrolled, or BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE if none are currently supported/enabled. 
>   Returns BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS if a biometric can currently be used (enrolled and available). Value is BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS, BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE, BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED, or BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE

Comment: Thank you, but I need to test the sensor,if it functions correctly. This is my question.